# Screen resolutions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, screen-resolution

Android devices have screen resolutions such as mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.
When programming in Android, I do different coding for phones with these resolutions.
But Flutter is a development environment for both android and ios. Do I have to do separate programming for android and ios phones with different resolutions?
Are there resolutions like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi in ios?

Comment: You can look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.50,
)
```